# Angular and CSS animation with fade-in drop down effect

Tags: html, css, typescript, animation

I'm working on a portfolio site for myself but I keep getting this odd behavior with my css animations that I am not interested in. In my mind how it is supposed to work is when someone visits my site the header links should fade-in from the top. Once they have faded into place, if I hover the mouse cursor over the links, it should play a pulsate-into-fading animation and repeat for as long as the mouse cursor is over the link. All of this works properly.

The problem comes into play when I try to delay the initial animation for the fade-in from the top animation so I can achieve a kind of like "step" or "cascading" animation where the first link drops down and fades into location, a second later the second link drops down and fades in, then after two seconds the third link drops down and fades in. If I delay the animation, I lose the drop down effect and only the fade in effect plays.

This is the snippet where all three links fade-in and drop down into place.

```css
.myNav{
    height: 64px;
    background-color: #4b5778;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.navItem{
    margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    /* color: white; */
    /* color: rgb(182, 181, 181); */
    color: greenyellow;
    /* transform: scale(1.00);
    transition: transform 1s; */
}

.fade-in-text{
    animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
    -o-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
    -ms-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
}

.navItem:hover{
    /* transform: scale(1.33);
    transition: transform 1s; */
    animation: pulsate-in 1.2s ease-out infinite;
    /* color: white; */
    color: rgb(222, 255, 173);
}

/* pulsating text animation */
@keyframes pulsate-in {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.50;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.25);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

/* fading text animation */
@keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {opacity: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;}
    100% {opacity: 1; margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;}
}

/* Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {opacity: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;}
    100% {opacity: 1; margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;}
}
 
/* Safari and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {opacity: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;}
    100% {opacity: 1; margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;}
}

/* Opera */
@-o-keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {opacity: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;}
    100% {opacity: 1; margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;}
}
```

```html
<nav class="myNav">
    <ul id="menu">
        <!-- <li (mouseover)="increment()" class="fade-in-text navItem">Intro</li> -->
        <li (click)="scroll(intro)" #intro class="fade-in-text navItem myIntro ">Intro</li>
        <li (click)="scroll(projects)" #projects class="fade-in-text navItem myProjects">Projects</li>
        <li (click)="scroll(resume)" #resume class="fade-in-text navItem myResume">Resume</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the snippet of the animation that plays if I try doing the animation delay to get the "cascading" effect.

```css
.myNav{
    height: 64px;
    background-color: #4b5778;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.navItem{
    margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    /* color: white; */
    /* color: rgb(182, 181, 181); */
    color: greenyellow;
    /* transform: scale(1.00);
    transition: transform 1s; */
}

.fade-in-text{
    animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
    -o-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
    -ms-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
}

.fade-in-text-two{
    animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s 2s;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
    -o-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
    -ms-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
}

.fade-in-text-three{
    animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s 3s;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
    -o-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
    -ms-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
}

.navItem:hover{
    /* transform: scale(1.33);
    transition: transform 1s; */
    animation: pulsate-in 1.2s ease-out infinite;
    /* color: white; */
    color: rgb(222, 255, 173);
}

/* pulsating text animation */
@keyframes pulsate-in {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.50;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.25);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

/* fading text animation */
@keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {opacity: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;}
    100% {opacity: 1; margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;}
}

/* Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {opacity: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;}
    100% {opacity: 1; margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;}
}
 
/* Safari and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {opacity: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;}
    100% {opacity: 1; margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;}
}

/* Opera */
@-o-keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {opacity: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;}
    100% {opacity: 1; margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;}
}
```

```html
<nav class="myNav">
    <ul id="menu">
        <!-- <li (mouseover)="increment()" class="fade-in-text navItem">Intro</li> -->
        <li (click)="scroll(intro)" #intro class="fade-in-text navItem myIntro ">Intro</li>
        <li (click)="scroll(projects)" #projects class="fade-in-text-two navItem myProjects">Projects</li>
        <li (click)="scroll(resume)" #resume class="fade-in-text-three navItem myResume">Resume</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried using nth of type to select each list element individually and then tried giving each a class (as shown in the code). Not sure why I keep getting this behavior. I am running this on Angular. My last resort was to "inject" the class into each element after a delay using TypeScript but I would rather get it done working with css the right way if it is possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

Give your items that you're animating values to start from and add `forwards` to your animation.

```css
.fade-in-text{
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;
  animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s forwards;
}
```

Then you can use `:nth-of-type(n)` for your animation delays.

```css
 .fade-in-text:nth-of-type(2) {
      animation-delay: .2s;
  }

 .fade-in-text:nth-of-type(3) {
      animation-delay: .3s;
  }
```

```css
.myNav{
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #4b5778;
  text-align: center;

}

.navItem{
  margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* color: white; */
  /* color: rgb(182, 181, 181); */
  color: greenyellow;
  /* transform: scale(1.00);
  transition: transform 1s; */
}

.fade-in-text{
 opacity: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;
  animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s forwards;
  -o-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s forwards;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s forwards;
}

.fade-in-text:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

.fade-in-text:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

.navItem:hover{
  /* transform: scale(1.33);
  transition: transform 1s; */
  animation: pulsate-in 1.2s ease-out infinite;
  /* color: white; */
  color: rgb(222, 255, 173);
}

/* pulsating text animation */
@keyframes pulsate-in {
  0% {
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
      opacity: 0.50;
  }
  100% {
      transform: scale(1.25);
      opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* fading text animation */
@keyframes fadeIn{
  0% {opacity: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;}
  100% {opacity: 1; margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;}
}

/* Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn{
  0% {opacity: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;}
  100% {opacity: 1; margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;}
}

/* Safari and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{
  0% {opacity: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;}
  100% {opacity: 1; margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;}
}

/* Opera */
@-o-keyframes fadeIn{
  0% {opacity: 0; margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px;}
  100% {opacity: 1; margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;}
}
```

```html
<nav class="myNav">
    <ul id="menu">
        <!-- <li (mouseover)="increment()" class="fade-in-text navItem">Intro</li> -->
        <li (click)="scroll(intro)" #intro class="fade-in-text navItem myIntro ">Intro</li>
        <li (click)="scroll(projects)" #projects class="fade-in-text navItem myProjects">Projects</li>
        <li (click)="scroll(resume)" #resume class="fade-in-text navItem myResume">Resume</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: YES!! That is what I have been trying to achieve! Thank you so much! Why is the forwards attribute required in this case? I thought it was an implication that the animation would go forwards. I really appreciate the help and pointers!

Comment: Happy I could help! Without the `forwards`, the animation will return to the original values. Remove it and test it out to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're trying to animate margin, and when you increase the margin of the first element it affects the others as well and they become visible.

I've fixed this using `position: relative` and `top` so that they fall individually (so that the change in property of one element doesn't affect the other):

```css
.myNav {
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #4b5778;
  text-align: center;
}

.navItem {
  position: relative;
  margin: 18px 0px 0px 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* color: white; */
  /* color: rgb(182, 181, 181); */
  color: greenyellow;
  /* transform: scale(1.00);
    transition: transform 1s; */
}

.fade-in-text {
  animation: fadeIn ease-out 1s;
}

.fade-in-text-two {
  animation: fadeIn ease-out 1.5s;
}

.fade-in-text-three {
  animation: fadeIn ease-out 2s;
}

.navItem:hover {
  animation: pulsate-in 1.2s ease-out infinite;
  color: rgb(222, 255, 173);
}


/* fading text animation */

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -40px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
  }
}


/* pulsating text animation */

@keyframes pulsate-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.50;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.25);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="myNav">
  <ul id="menu">
    <!-- <li (mouseover)="increment()" class="fade-in-text navItem">Intro</li> -->
    <li (click)="scroll(intro)" #intro class="fade-in-text navItem myIntro ">Intro</li>
    <li (click)="scroll(projects)" #projects class="fade-in-text-two navItem myProjects">Projects</li>
    <li (click)="scroll(resume)" #resume class="fade-in-text-three navItem myResume">Resume</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ah okay I understand a bit more. Thank you for pointing out what my problem was! I was stuck on this for two days trying out different options. As my great professor once said, "Don't throw garbage at your code and go deeper into the swamp."